# My website suddenly started to show border over png files in ie 8

Tags: css, cross-browser, png

My website moviesmalayalam.com, suddenly started to show border over png files in ie 8. It was working fine a few days before and this started after I tweked the css file. I can't find what I changed. Can anybody help to find this bug. There is no problem in crome and firefox.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise: what's your CSS / HTML?, what did you change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The borders are appearing around images that are being used as links.  This is default behaviour for IE, and suggests that at some point you have removed the CSS rule that prevents it.

Try adding something like this to your CSS:

```
a img {
    border:0;
}
```